# jwplayer 6 setup no longer supports event callbacks. how to tell when player is ready if I cannot specify onReady callback within setup?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, jwplayer

I am trying to migrate from jw5 to jw6.  In jw5, I included event callbacks within the player setup.  For example:

```
var myplayer = jwplayer('container').setup({
  flashplayer:  /my/player.swf',
  height: '100%',
  width: '100%', 
  events: {
    'onReady': function(event) {
       alert ("on ready");
    },
    'onPlay': function(event) {
       alert ("on play");
    },        
  }
});
```

According to the jw5-to-jw6 migration [documentation](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28834/migrating-from-jw5-to-jw6), it seems I can no longer include event callbacks within the player setup:

> Removed: the events configuration block
>       This way of adding event listeners is fully redundant with adding listeners outside the setup, both in terms of features and amount of code required.

If I understand correctly, I am supposed to specify the event callbacks this way:

```
myplayer.onReady( function(event){
  alert('on ready');
});
myplayer.onPlay( function(event){
  alert('on play');
});
```

My Question:

It seems to me I need to wait for the myplayer object to be ready, before I can define these myplayer event callbacks.  True?  How do I know when myplayer is ready, if I cannot specify the onReady event callback within the setup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In JWPlayer6 you can add `onReady` event handler the same way you add others. This works for me:

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "test.mp4"
});

playerInstance.onReady(function() {
    console.log('ready');

    playerInstance.onPlay(function() {
        console.log('playing');
    });

    playerInstance.play();
});
```

Comment: I gave this a try, but it's not working for me.  (Using the firebug debugger, I see that "console.log('ready')" is never executed.)

Comment: Do you have any other errors/logs in firebug? Maybe you have incorrect path to swf player or something else. I recommend you to start with basic example like I did - just download JWplayer files and try code above with it.

Comment: thank you, this is working for me now.  the problem was that i was using an uncompressed version of jwplayer,js to debug a different problem.  when i went back to using the original compressed version of jwplayer.js, onReady callbacks work.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is, that you have a typo in your last code block: it should be `myplayer.onReady()` ;-)

Furthermore the event handlers get hooked up to the corresponding objects as soon as they are proceeded.

So I think you should simply put your jwplayer setup and `onReady` & `onPlay` events into `$(document).ready()`.

I think this should work as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot put my jwplayer setup and event callbacks within $(document).ready().  I am trying to develop a jwplayer plugin for the mediafront player, which would load the jwplayer dynamically, as needed.

Comment: @moondog Okay! Have you take a look to the other answer?